# Ошибка при работе с xsl

Tags: xslt

такая проблема, нужно xml представить в виде html, для чего я использую xsl-файл. Всё работает, но при добавлении поиска для сайта Яндекс, браузер выдаёт ошибку.
Код, на который ругается браузер:

```html
<div class="ya-site-form ya-site-form_inited_no" onclick="return {'action':'http://мойсайт.com','arrow':false,'bg':'transparent','fontsize':16,'fg':'#000000','language':'ru','logo':'rb','publicname':'Поиск по мойсайт.com','suggest':true,'target':'_self','tld':'ru','type':2,'usebigdictionary':true,'searchid':2330933,'input_fg':'#000000','input_bg':'#ffffff','input_fontStyle':'normal','input_fontWeight':'normal','input_placeholder':null,'input_placeholderColor':'#000000','input_borderColor':'#7f9db9'}">
```

ошибка:

> Ошибка загрузки таблицы стилей: Ошибка разбора выражения XPath, символ «:» здесь запрещён:

Как исправить данную ошибку? Может можно разрешить как-то использовать двоеточия? Не работает этот код именно в xsl (а мне это очень надо).

Comment: Используйте екранирование. Для : код 58 т.е. `&#3A;` Потом разекранируете.

Comment: извините, можно пожалуйста подробнее, как это сделать?

Comment: Где сам код XSL? Или єта строка у вас как есть записана в xsl?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov она так и записана

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас в использовании скобок `{}` которые xslt процессор воспринимает как попытку вычислить значение.

Решений проблемы 2.

1. Заэкранировать их символами `&#x7B;` `&#x7D;`. При этом заэкранировав сам символ `&` как `&amp;`

   ```
   <div class="ya-site-form ya-site-form_inited_no"
     onclick="return &amp;#x7B;'action':'http://мойсайт.com','arrow':false,'bg':'transparent','fontsize':16,'fg':'#000000','language':'ru','logo':'rb','publicname':'Поиск по мойсайт.com','suggest':true,'target':'_self','tld':'ru','type':2,'usebigdictionary':true,'searchid':2330933,'input_fg':'#000000','input_bg':'#ffffff','input_fontStyle':'normal','input_fontWeight':'normal','input_placeholder':null,'input_placeholderColor':'#000000','input_borderColor':'#7f9db9' &amp;#x7B;" />
   ```
2. Либо использовать элемент `<xsl:attribute>`

   ```
   <div class="ya-site-form ya-site-form_inited_no">
     <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
       return {'action':'http://мойсайт.com','arrow':false,'bg':'transparent','fontsize':16,'fg':'#000000','language':'ru','logo':'rb','publicname':'Поиск по мойсайт.com','suggest':true,'target':'_self','tld':'ru','type':2,'usebigdictionary':true,'searchid':2330933,'input_fg':'#000000','input_bg':'#ffffff','input_fontStyle':'normal','input_fontWeight':'normal','input_placeholder':null,'input_placeholderColor':'#000000','input_borderColor':'#7f9db9'}
     </xsl:attribute>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Просто от души!)) спасибо большое!! очень помогли)